# how to avoid black screen when activity is busy for start playing video from server

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am opening an activity on a button click, next activity is for playing video from server if i click on button, it happens black and after 5-6 sec it starts playing video,how could avoid that black screen.?

Here is my code:

```
mPreview=new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext()); 
l1.addView(mPreview); 
holder = mPreview.getHolder(); 
holder.addCallback(this);
holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

Following content is of surfacecreted method.

```
        path = "http://www.pixintro.com/upload/video/Benetton.mp4";
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Benetton.mp4");
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer){
       mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = true;
       if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown){
               holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
               mMediaPlayer.start();
       }
}
```

Comment: can you add the `onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)` code ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [async task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)  . While the processing is being done in doInBackground() ie in background .You can display a progress dialog(onPreExecute())  which is dismissed as soon as  the task is done (onPostExecute).

```
public class DisplayActivity extends Activity {
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
          // create surface view etc
              new Operation().execute();
}



}

 private class Operation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // code to be executed in background thread 

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
    try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    return "Executed";
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // runs on UI thread and updated UI after executing doInBackground
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Title ", "Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    // runs on UI thread and starts first

    }
    }
```

Comment: is it correct way to play video from background task.? as i need to create surface view for video and will do in back ground allow me to add surface view to activity

Comment: you can add view in our activity's oncreate() and then call this class  new Operation ().execute(); from on craete .Here you can prepare and buffer your media player in background.Till the video is ready ,a progress dialog will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks for Your help. I am trying to changes the code and will let you the result

Comment: It didnot properly worked as i click on btton it sticks there for 2 sec and then goes to next screen, and progress is stable there no movement and video starts playing after some sec.        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
               holder = mPreview.getHolder();
         holder.addCallback(MediaPlayerDemo_Video.this);
         
         
         
         

        return "Executed";
        }

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html) interface. It contains a callback when the media is ready to play.

MediaPlayer also have a prepareAsync method. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) for more details